# Running php web application in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, web

I am trying to run an "helo world" php page from eclipse. Running the page as a php cli application works, but running it web application open a page with localhost url and page path, and informs that it can't reach this page. I can see that the php.exe that I have added defined as "cli", do I need to do something more in order to run a php web application? if the answer is yes - what?

[image]

[image]